# List all servers a user is connected to using remote desktop

Tags: active-directory, rdp

Is there a way to list all servers, that a given user is logged into in the entire active directory?

Something like...:

```
QueryRdpConnections -user BobAdmin
```

Result...:

```
Server         
----------------
Web001
Web002
Web003
SQL004
SQL007
```

Comment: @Froggiz Did you read the question? The scope of the query is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use qwinsta in powershell:

```
QUERY SESSION [sessionname | username | sessionid]
              [/SERVER:servername] [/MODE] [/FLOW] [/CONNECT] [/COUNTER] [/VM]

  sessionname         Identifies the session named sessionname.
  username            Identifies the session with user username.
  sessionid           Identifies the session with ID sessionid.
  /SERVER:servername  The server to be queried (default is current).
  /MODE               Display current line settings.
  /FLOW               Display current flow control settings.
  /CONNECT            Display current connect settings.
  /COUNTER            Display current Remote Desktop Services counters information.
  /VM                 Display information about sessions within virtual machines.
```

A quick search gets you [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-script-to-Find-d2ba4252) article on technet.

I'm using the following part of the script to querry all the active servers and find what users are remotely logged in:

```
function QueryRdpConnections {
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
# Import the Active Directory module for the Get-ADComputer CmdLet 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

#Query Active Directory for computers running a Server operating system 
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*server*" -and Enabled -eq 'true'} 

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) { 
    $ServerName = $Server.Name 


# Run the qwinsta.exe and parse the output 
$queryResults = (qwinsta /SERVER:$ServerName | foreach { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+",","))} | ConvertFrom-Csv)

# Pull the session information from each instance 
ForEach ($queryResult in $queryResults) { 
$RDPUser = $queryResult.USERNAME
$sessionType = $queryResult.SESSIONNAME 

# We only want to display where a "person" is logged in. Otherwise unused sessions show up as USERNAME as a number 
If (($RDPUser -match "[a-z]") -and ($RDPUser -ne $NULL)) {  

Write-Host $ServerName logged in by $RDPUser on $sessionType 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run it from powershell_ise and just edit on line 22 the $RDPuser -match "%%%" to $RDPuser -match "user1/2/3/" in order to run for a specific user. If you run it as is it will display all users logged in by rdp.